# CallLog Generator Error - Android Development

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement some fake call logs in Android Studio. When I run the emulator with the application installed, it firstly says Launcher 3 has stopped working, Then when I click the add call log button it says 'unfortunately the callLog app has stopped working'. I think I might need something within the resolver if statement as, it is highlighted in red and shows a prompt that user permission is required. The code from the main activity class is:

```
    package com.example.calllogexample;

    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.provider.CallLog;
    import android.util.Log;


    public class CallLogActivity {

     public void AddNumToCallLog(ContentResolver resolver ,String strNum, int type, long timeInMiliSecond) {
         while (strNum.contains("-")) {
             strNum = strNum.substring(0, strNum.indexOf('-')) + strNum.substring(strNum.indexOf('-') + 1, strNum.length());
         }
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, strNum);
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, timeInMiliSecond);
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 0);
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, type);
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "");
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");
         Log.d("AddToCallLog", "Inserting call log placeholder for " + strNum);

         if (null != resolver) {
             resolver.insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
         }
     }

        public void DeleteNumFromCallLog(ContentResolver resolver, String strNum) {
            try {
                String strUriCalls = "content://call_log/calls";
                Uri UriCalls = Uri.parse(strUriCalls);
                if (null != resolver) {
                    resolver.delete(UriCalls, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + "=?", new String[]{strNum});
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

write permission in your manifest file under manifest tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Comment: <uses-permission        android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>

Comment: They are the permissions that I have in my manifest. Sorry about the messy comment above, I wasn't sure how to comment properly